# Single feature highlight on hover

Tags: vue.js, echarts

map.js :

> https://github.com/ro-hit81/COVID-19-Vuetify/blob/master/src/assets/map.js

timeline.vue:

> https://github.com/ro-hit81/COVID-19-Vuetify/blob/master/src/views/Timeline.vue

Actually it is going to be a confusing query I guess and it might get difficult for me to make my problem understandable. I am actually using 'Vue js' and 'Echarts js' to create a Map of my country with some temporal point data. The problem may be minor but I am not able to figure out to solve.

While importing China.json file in my .js file, I can see 'Province' is highlighted on hover as:
[image: China data]

Now, without changing any code, only importing  Nepal.json file inplace of China.json, I see whole layer is highlighted on hover.
[image: Nepal data]
I want single feature (as in 'Province' in case of China data , similarly 'District' in case of Nepal data) to be highlighted on hover.

I tried my best to make this problem understandable. Please tell me kindly if i have to attach code.

Comment: share your code ?

Comment: I have attached links for my code.